# How to read NVARCHAR2 Data from oracle with php

Tags: php, oracle

I have a project where I am using ORACLE Database and CakePHP framework. I have a column where the datatype is NVARCHAR2. If I try to read the data from the database I get "¿¿¿¿¿". The code I am using is

```
ociexecute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);     
$i = 0;
$result = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {         
       foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $result[$i][$key] = $value;
            }
            $i++;
}
```

Charset in my Database is -

> NLS_LANGUAGE  AMERICAN NLS_TERRITORY  AMERICA
>   NLS_CHARACTERSET  WE8MSWIN1252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `oci_connect` is requesting data in UTF-8 like so:

```
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $conn_string, 'UTF8');
```

As described in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php), the Oracle client libraries will then handle conversion automatically:

> The character set does not need to match the character set used by the database. If it doesn't match, Oracle will do its best to convert data to and from the database character set.

As long as you are outputting your results as UTF-8 the characters should render correctly.